# SSIS 2008 - how to do regular expression search in SSIS Derived Column tool

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

How do I do a regular expression in an SSIS Derived Column Tool

i.e.

I have string in the format XXXNNNN and I want to filter our those strings not in this format using an SSIS Derived Column Tool.

i.e

ABC1234 is ok

ABCDEFG is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Derived Column transformation doesn't support regular expressions, so you'll have to look at some other options:

1. Use a Script Task and write the regex using the standard .NET regex features
2. Use a [third-party component](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Regular-Expression-Transformation.aspx)
3. If you always have 7 characters, you could use the `SUBSTRING` and `CODEPOINT` functions to check that each one is in the range you expect (see the [function reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141671.aspx)). But that's probably awkward to read and maintain, and may not be practical at all depending on what your data looks like.